Is there a way to place the AG across WSFC?
I have a 2 node production application AG. Both nodes are part of the same WSFC. Primary is read/write and secondary is read only. This has the db called APP_DB.
I also have a 2 node BI reporting AG. Both nodes are part of the same WSFC. Primary is read/write and secondary is read only. This has the db called BI_DB.
The BI reporting SQL nodes have linked server setup to point to the production application AG (readintent).
We also have SSIS packages on BI reporting SQL nodes that fetch data from production application AG (readintent).
Due to performance reasons related to the linked server and SSIS, I want to explore possibility of having the APP_DB synced and made available on the BI SQL servers.
What are my options?
One is replication but that isn't applicable as the app_db has things like truncate, user defined data types, etc and due to the nature of maintenance I want to avoid using replication.
The other is log shipping but that can potentially break the read only queries when the restore occurs so not an option.
Maybe can we have the app_db AG placed on the BI SQL that sits in a separate WSFC, is that possible? Any other options?

We have some tables getting new names each day so replication is not an option.

By perfomance reasons I'm referring to things like having to move about 50GB on data incrementally each day from App SQL server to BI SQL srver via ETLs. We also see large async network io waits. Hoping that placing the db on BI SQL server will improve performance.


Is there a way to place the AG across WSFC?


I want to explore possibility of having the APP_DB synced and made available on the BI SQL servers.


Maybe can we have the app_db AG placed on the BI SQL that sits in a separate WSFC, is that possible?

Yes, using a distributed availability group.

For that I will need to get rid of my existing AG as a db cannot live inside a normal AG and a distributed AG together

That's incorrect, you can't create a distributed AG without an AG in place.
